# MongoDB and Heroku Synchronization Problem

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, heroku

So I made a learner `ToDo Management Python-Flask App` and have used `Atlas MongoDB Cloud` to store my data. When I was running this app on production environment i.e `localhost` it works completely fine, data retrieval and updation was completely going smooth, but as soon as I deployed it on `Heroku` it starts working so bad that whenever I add a task to my list, it doesn't even bother displaying it on my list, and also I have added a Login System so that different users can manage their own tasks, but on heroku the synchronization became so bad that it even starts showing the tasks of other users, when I search for it I found out that my app is working completely fine like task getting added and marked as completed on MongoDB server and the problem was with the synchronization between heroku and mongodb, for some reason heroku is not able to fetch the data from mongodb server `on time`. Is there any possible solution for this because I have a major project coming up that is based on same strategy. Also, does this problem only occurs on heroku or on other deployment tools as well.
Here's my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/YashasviBhatt/GovNaB-ToDo-App) where I have posted my source code.

Here are my logs:

```
2021-04-15T06:48:00.026431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-15T06:48:02.063224+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.178.208 - - [15/Apr/2021:06:48:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 829 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
2021-04-15T06:48:02.064514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=f39fbf24-11a7-47e1-81bb-d83937124967 fwd="157.47.233.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=983 protocol=https
2021-04-15T06:48:02.413446+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.178.208 - - [15/Apr/2021:06:48:02 +0000] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
2021-04-15T06:48:02.414936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/styles.css" host=govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b61d727a-931c-45c3-8500-9e2cc9e9f00b fwd="157.47.233.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=5289 protocol=https
2021-04-15T06:50:45.869482+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.232.203 - - [15/Apr/2021:06:50:45 +0000] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1804 "https://govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
2021-04-15T06:50:45.870036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login/" host=govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1aa542b5-49cb-4cc1-832a-4c0f3d335488 fwd="157.47.233.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=1959 protocol=https
2021-04-15T06:50:46.329593+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.232.203 - - [15/Apr/2021:06:50:46 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
2021-04-15T06:50:46.330591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b7be2322-abbc-41b6-aa62-ff627b7946e6 fwd="157.47.233.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-04-15T06:51:00.129383+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.234.207 - - [15/Apr/2021:06:51:00 +0000] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 229 "https://govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
2021-04-15T06:51:00.130615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login/" host=govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=4ddc513b-8608-4f0e-b046-638bf7bfade1 fwd="157.47.233.216" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2338ms status=302 bytes=619 protocol=https
2021-04-15T06:51:00.687977+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.234.207 - - [15/Apr/2021:06:51:00 +0000] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2392 "https://govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com/login/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
2021-04-15T06:51:00.689168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dashboard/" host=govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com request_id=e7eb83a9-7efa-4e05-8c1d-6c8150e9dffa fwd="157.47.233.216" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=154ms status=200 bytes=2561 protocol=https
```

Here are my Build Logs:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.9.4
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting click==7.1.2
         Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
       Collecting dnspython==2.1.0
         Downloading dnspython-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
       Collecting Flask==1.1.2
         Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
       Collecting Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
         Downloading Flask_PyMongo-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0.tar.gz (370 kB)
       Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
         Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting Jinja2==2.11.3
         Downloading Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
       Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
         Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
       Collecting passlib==1.7.4
         Downloading passlib-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (525 kB)
       Collecting pymongo==3.11.3
         Downloading pymongo-3.11.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (518 kB)
       Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.1
         Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: gunicorn
         Building wheel for gunicorn (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for gunicorn (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for gunicorn: filename=gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=78917 sha256=a2046e4ea7addea07a09c2278d261a39b0bde95e2d30613cf0b1ccb955c981e9
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-9yc9nl7p/wheels/ee/ca/72/3e9be4033d3993d4d78e2f4accdfcfff6c690921fef5ea0d57
       Successfully built gunicorn
       Installing collected packages: click, dnspython, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, Flask, pymongo, Flask-PyMongo, gunicorn, passlib
       Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Flask-PyMongo-2.3.0 Jinja2-2.11.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 click-7.1.2 dnspython-2.1.0 gunicorn-20.1.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0 passlib-1.7.4 pymongo-3.11.3
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 60.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://govnab-todo-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Can you post logs from Heroku?

Comment: you want build logs ?

Comment: @BeppeC I have added Heroku Logs

Comment: Is GitHub the latest version of your code? I don't see where you configure Flask to set the Heroku `PORT`

Comment: the app is taking configurations from my `bitbucket private repository` since my source contains credentials to mongodb server, cluster details and all those things, the basic code is completely similar, its just bitbucket version have my own credentials which are not in the `GitHub` version

Comment: and I haven't set any Heroku PORT, is the problem due to that ?

Comment: also I haven't installed any add-ons for my app, do I need some on heroku ?

Comment: No addons are necessary. Typically a Flask app requires the port to be set (`app.run(debug=False, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)), host='0.0.0.0')`) but I don't see any error so it seems to deploy

Comment: Cannot see what is wrong with your code. You can check this Medium post https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/1-2-3-docker-heroku-mongodb-atlas-python-952958423bea which explains how I setup Flask on Heroku connecting to AtlasDB